# Creating a text file from script in unity3d is having a delay / error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

EDIT * Called AssetDatabase.Refresh and the file appears in the editor now but with a loading icon and cannot be written to for some time still. The file was previously showing in the chosen location on the SSD just not in unity.*

I am creating a text file in unity from a script, then the next line i try to write to that file.
The issue is the file is not created before the next line is executed, i can toggle the play button off and on for the editor and the file is still not there and it only appears when i minimize the editor or open another program and then go back. I can stop play on the editor with the file not there then minimize and maximize the editor window and it will appear where i chose to create it. Hopefully i'm explaining my issue correctly.

This is the code below

```
public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{

public static GameObject itemContainerPrefab;
private string dataPath;
private string jsonData;
private Dictionary<string, Item> items = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
private Dictionary<string, GameObject> prefabs = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
private JSONDataWrapper wrapper;

private void Awake()
{
    
    File.Create(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/JSON/HELLOFILE.json");
    File.WriteAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/JSON/HELLOFILE.json", "hello");
    itemContainerPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Item/ItemContainer");
    dataPath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/JSON/ItemData.json";
    jsonData = File.ReadAllText(dataPath);
    wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<JSONDataWrapper>(jsonData);
    wrapper.Initialize();
    BuildDatabase();
   
}
```

Any suggestions on why the first line is completed in such a strange way? the rest of the code wont execute until the file is created and the next line can write to that file.
I have tried this with both File.Create and File.CreateText and get the same issue.
I have also tried doing it in both the Awake and start methods

Answer (score 0):

The file should exist on disk almost immediately. If you are saying it does not exist in Unity, then yes that makes sense. You would need to call [AssetDatabase.Refresh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html). Once called, the assets should appear where you are looking for them.

If the issue is that the file actually does not exist and you are getting an error, what is the error? Can you post it?

Comment: Yes to clarify it is appearing in the folder on my SSD instantly but not in the unity editor. I have tried AssetDatabase.Refresh and the file appears in the editor but just has a loading icon on it and is unable to be written to until i make a script change and unity compiles again

Comment: Try using `CompilationPipeline.RequestScriptCompilation()`. There is a callback for when it finishes too `CompilationPipeline.assemblyCompilationFinished` subscribe a function to it before calling it then handle your write after it is called.